# Trying to pack binary bits represented by bytes into a byte using String.pack with Hex escaped Sequence(i.e. \x equivalent) format in Lua

Tags: string, lua, hex, byte, pack

I want to to pack binary bits represented by bytes into a byte using String.pack with Hex escaped Sequence(i.e. \x equivalent) format in Lua.But I don't Know How.Infact I have a function in python that do this. and I want to do this in Lua Too But I have problem
**Function in Lua:**

```
MESSAGE_HEADER_FMT = ">4I"
PREFIX_VALUE = 0x000055AA
def pack_message_test():
    buffer = (
        struct.pack(
            MESSAGE_HEADER_FMT,
            PREFIX_VALUE,
            2,
            7,
            121,
        )
    )
    return buffer
```

```
print(pack_message_test())
```

**The ouput of python function is:**

> b'\x00\x00U\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00y'

**then I want do the same thing in Lua Language.  so I write this Function in Lua:**

```
function Pack:create(fmt,ps_value,body_len)
    local pack = {}
    local pattern = fmt
    

    pack.cmd = 7
    pack.seqno = 2
    pack.prefix_value = ps_value
    pack.body_len = body_len
    
    
    function pack:split()
       return self.prefix_value,self.seqno,self.cmd,body_len
    end

    function pack:hex()
       return string.pack(pattern,self:split())
    end
    
    return pack
end
```

```
pack = Pack:create(">I4",0x000055AA,121)
hex_packet = pack:hex()
```

**The ouput of Lua function is:**

> U¬

**I want to give the same output as python function in Lua function.
what is the problem and how fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your pack template in lua is not doing the same thing as the python one. The python template, '>4I', will pack 4 ints in big endian byte order. The lua template, '>I4', on the other hand, will pack 1 int whose width is 4 bytes in big endian byte order. So you need to be be using a template like: '>I4I4I4I4' to pack your data in lua.

UPDATE:

To display the packed binary data as a hex string as python does, you'll need to write a function to do that. Here's one way:

```
function to_hex_string(s)
    local hex = ''
    local fmt = string.rep('B', #s)
    for  i, v in ipairs(table.pack(string.unpack(fmt, s))) do
        hex = hex .. string.format("\\x%02x", v)
    end
    return hex
end

local p = string.pack(">I4I4I4I4", 0x000055AA, 2, 7, 121)
print(to_hex_string(p))
```